# Mac sandbox: running a binary tool that needs /tmp

Tags: c, macos, appstore-sandbox

I have a sandboxed Cocoa app that, during an export process, needs to run a third party command-line tool. This tool appears to be hardcoded to use `/tmp` for its temporary files; sandboxing doesn't permit access to this folder, so the export fails.

How can I get this tool to run? I don't have access to its source code, so I can't modify it to use `NSTemporaryDirectory()`, and it doesn't appear to respect the `TMP` or `TEMPDIR` environment variables. For reasons I don't understand, giving myself a `com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-write` entitlement doesn't seem to work, either.

Is there some way to re-map folders within my sandbox? Is there some obscure trick I can use? Should I try to patch the tool's binary somehow? I'm at my wit's end here.

Comment: One solution which instantly come to my mind is to use `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` as described e.g. [here](http://tlrobinson.net/blog/2007/12/overriding-library-functions-in-mac-os-x-the-easy-way-dyld_insert_libraries/) and override `open/fopen` and other relevant syscalls

Comment: Also you may need to `dtrace` that third-party tool, checking what system calls you need to override. [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) seems to be a handful command-line frontend to the DTrace MacOSX kernel facility.

Comment: Can you control how the tool accessing /tmp is launched? If you can substitute its invocation with a custom script, then you've got the solution. If no, then some additional tricks are required.

Comment: I'm launching the tool via `NSTask`. I tried `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` about a year ago, and it didn't work because (believe it or not) `-[NSTask setEnvironment:]` doesn't seem to do anything, at least in a sandbox. However, calling POSIX `setenv(3)` before launching does seem to at least set environment variables that can be seen with `/usr/bin/env`. I may try this tomorrow.

Comment: Got it! @user3159253, if you write up something about `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, I'll be happy to give you the bounty.

Comment: @user3159253, the bounty expires in less than a day. If you want to claim it, please write something up!

Comment: Oh, excuse me, please! These days I'm almost offline so when I saw that you had resolved your problem successfully, I forgot to claim the prize! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since @BrentRoyal-Gordon has already published a working solution I'm simply duplicating my comment which inspired him to produce the solution:

In order to fix a program behavior, I would intercept and override some system calls with the help of [DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html) and a custom shared library with a custom implementation of the given system calls.

The exact list of the syscalls which need to be overridden depends on nature of the application and can be studied with a number of tools built upon MacOS DTrace kernel facility. E.g. [dtruss](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dtruss.1m.html) or [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com). @BrentRoyal-Gordon has investigated that the app can be fixed solely with an /appropriate/ implementation of `mkstemp`.

That's it. I'm still not sure that I've deserved the bounty :)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get user3159253's `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES` approach to work. I'm hoping they will write an answer describing how that works, so I'll leave the details of that out and explain the parts that ended up being specific to this case.

Thanks to LLDB, elbow grease, and not a little help from [Hopper](http://hopperapp.com/), I was able to determine that the third-party tool used `mkstemp()` to generate its temporary file names, and some calls (not all) used a fixed template starting with `/tmp`. I then wrote a libtmphack.dylib that intercepted calls to `mkstemp()` and modified the parameters before calling the standard library version.

Since `mkstemp()` takes a pointer to a preallocated buffer, I didn't feel like I could rewrite a path starting with a short string like "/tmp" to the very long string needed to get to the Caches folder inside the sandbox. Instead, I opted to create a symlink to it called "$tmp" in the current working directory. This could break if the tool `chdir()`'d at an inopportune time, but fortunately it doesn't seem to do that.

Here's my code:

```
//
//  libtmphack.c
//  Typesetter
//
//  Created by Brent Royal-Gordon on 8/27/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Groundbreaking Software. This file is MIT licensed.
//

#include "libtmphack.h"
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

static int gbs_has_prefix(char * needle, char * haystack) {
    return strncmp(needle, haystack, strlen(needle)) == 0;
}

int mkstemp(char *template) {
    static int (*original_mkstemp)(char * template) = NULL;

    if(!original_mkstemp) {
        original_mkstemp = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "mkstemp");
    }

    if(gbs_has_prefix("/tmp", template)) {
        printf("libtmphack: rewrote mkstemp(\"%s\") ", template);
        template[0] = '$';
        printf("to mkstemp(\"%s\")\n", template);

        // If this isn't successful, we'll presume it's because it's already been made
        symlink(getenv("TEMP"), "$tmp");

        int ret = original_mkstemp(template);

        // Can't do this, the caller needs to be able to open the file
        // int retErrno = errno;
        // unlink("$tmp");
        // errno = retErrno;

        return ret;
    }
    else {
        printf("libtmphack: OK with mkstemp(\"%s\")\n", template);
        return original_mkstemp(template);
    }
}
```

Very quick and dirty, but it works like a charm.

Comment: Quick and elegant, from a more civilized age.

Comment: @Prof.Falken I've been writing Objective-C for seven years; before that, I wrote C in a large open-source project (an interpreter) with fairly extensive libraries and abstraction layers; and before that, I learned computer science in C++. But I think this is the first code I've ever written in plain old C with no fancy libraries to help me.

Comment: Haha, with that background, I can see how plain unix-ish APIs can seem quick and dirty. :)

Answer (score 3):

Another solution would be to use `chroot` within the child process (or `posix_spawn` options) to change its root directory to a directory that is within your sandbox. Its “/tmp” will then be a “tmp” directory within that directory.